# Explicit isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a countable discrete group and consider $l^2(G)$ and let $H$ be any Hilbert space. What is the explicit isomorphism between the Hilbert space $l^2(G,H)$ and $l^2(G)\otimes H$.

Is it always true that if $X$ is any measure space, then $L^2(X,H)$ isomorphic to $L^2(X)\otimes H$ as Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Shouldn't the map $1_A\otimes v\mapsto v1_A$ extend to such an isomorphism for $A\subseteq X$ measurable and $v\in H$?

Comment: Where $v1_A$ is constantly equal to $v$ on $A$ and $0$ else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a measure space with measure $\mu$ and let $S$ denote the simple $H$-valued functions on sets of finite measure.

Define $\varphi$ from $S$ to the algebraic tensor product by $v1_A\mapsto 1_A\otimes v$, where $v\in H,$ $A\subseteq X$ is measurable with finite measure and $v 1_A$ is constantly equal to $v$ on $A$ and $0$ else.

Note  now that for $v,w\in H$ and $A,B\subseteq X$ measurable with finite measure,
$$
\int_X \langle v1_A,w1_B\rangle_H\textrm{d}\mu=\mu(A\cap B)\langle v,w\rangle_H=\langle 1_A 1_B\rangle_{L^2(X)} \langle v,w\rangle_H= \langle 1_A\otimes v,1_B\otimes w\rangle_{L^2(X)\otimes H},
$$
which implies that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of inner product spaces. Taking completions implies $L^2(X)\otimes H$ is isomorphic to $L^2(X,H)$.

Comment: That is an element of $S$ looks like $\sum_{i=1}^n \nu_i1_{A_i}$ where $\nu_i1_{A_i}$ is constantly equal to $\nu_i$ on $A_i$ and 0 otherwise where each $A_i$  has finite measure?

Comment: How can you approximate any element of $L^2(X,H)$  with elements of $S$?

Comment: Since $G$ is second countable $l^2(G)$ will have an onb. Can I take the indicator functions at a point in $G$, $\{\epsilon_g:g \in G\}$ to define the above map?

Comment: I don't think you need to change the proof that the simple functions are dense in $L^2(X)$ very much, but I didn't think about that. In the separable case, you should be able to take an increasing sequence of projections $(P_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ increasing to the identity and, for given $f\in L^2(X,H),$ approximate $P_nf$ by simple functions.

Comment: And of course, you can choose solely to define the above map on linear combinations of $v 1_{\{g\}}$ for $g\in G$. Then you just need to apply a density argument. This should work, since the singletons generate your $\sigma$-algebra.